# How can Python get a list from XML such as Unicode to a list?

Tags: python, xml, list, unicode

I have a problem reading XML. I want to get a 2D array. However, when I get the data from the XML, the type of data is Unicode. Hence, I type to use list(). However, the result is not what I want. Could I use another way to get a 2D list?

How can I remove u, \n, \t and get a correct answer? Thank you.

> abc.xml

```
<text>
    <item id="1">
        [[2, 2, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]]
    </item>  
</text>
```

PYTHON:

```
import  xml.dom.minidom

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse('abc.xml')

bb = dom.getElementsByTagName('item')
b=bb[0]

l= b.firstChild.data
print l

a=list(l)
print a
```

The OUTPUT:

```
[[2, 2, 1]
 [1, 0, 0] 
 [1, 0, 0]]

[u'\n', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u'\t', u'\t', u'[', u'\n', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u'\t', u'\t', u'\t', u'[', u'2', u',', u' ', u'2', u',', u' ', u'1', u']', u'\n', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u'\t', u'\t', u'\t', u'[', u'1', u',', u' ', u'0', u',', u' ', u'0', u']', u' ', u'\n', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u'\t', u'\t', u'\t', u'[', u'1', u',', u' ', u'0', u',', u' ', u'0', u']', u' ', u'\n', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u'\n', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u'\t', u'\t', u']', u'\n', u' ', u' ', u' ', u' ', u'\t']
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: you will have to parse text in `l` variable on your own.

Comment: I think `a=eval(l)` should work

Comment: `eval` should be used with extreme precaution, as it would exceute any code, not just return a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very similar to an old one: [Convert string representation of list to list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

In short, you want to *parse* a unicode string (`u"[\n[1,2,3],\n..."`) into an python list literal, so you want to do the same thing the python interpreter does while reading and parsing a program.

You can use the `ast` module for this:

```
import ast
a=ast.literal_eval(l)
```

in your case. Note that this function will evaluate *any* python literal, so if you simply put `"1"` in your xml, the result `a`will be the number `1`

See the [documentation for ast.literal_evel](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for more explanation.

Comment: It shows the new message again.[[2, 2, 1]IndentationError: unexpected indent What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

A little bit hacky but works for your case:

```
import ast
from lxml import html

text = """<text>
    <item id="1">
        [
            [2, 2, 1]
            [1, 0, 0] 
            [1, 0, 0] 

        ]
    </item>  
</text>"""

tree = html.fromstring(text)
data = ast.literal_eval(''.join([x.strip() for x in tree.xpath('//text/item[@id="1"]/text()')[0].replace('\n', '').replace(']','],').strip() if x.strip() !=""]).strip())[0]

print type(data)
print data
```

**Output:**

```
<type 'list'>
[[2, 2, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: i try use this way. It shows "IndexError: list index out of range". When i read the data from XML, it has not the tag (<text> <item id="1">). What should i change?

Comment: @HimYikTang then edit your question and provide a good XML file content sample

Answer (score 0):

You could just use mapping to convert unicode to string:

```
new_list = map(str, old_list)
```